# Multi-level push menu, I made the default open, how do I make the default closed for mobile?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mobile, menu, triggers

I'm using this multi-level push menu in the WordPress theme I'm creating: http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/index2.html

suggestion say to change the code to true see below:

```
_init : function() {
```

...
this.open = true;

But this did not work, so this other post on stack overflow says to change the code and add this, see below:

```
function mlPushMenu( el, trigger, options ) {
this.el = el;
this.trigger = trigger;
this.options = extend( this.defaults, options );
// support 3d transforms
this.support = Modernizr.csstransforms3d;
if( this.support ) {
    this._init();
    this._openMenu();  // added
}
```

}

This worked. But how do I change the default to close on a my mobile view 900px or less?

Comment: Here is my web link: http://worldwayssocialmarketing.org/louisiana/

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. Here is the answer if anyone needs it.

```
function mlPushMenu( el, trigger, options ) {   
    this.el = el;
    this.trigger = trigger;
    this.options = extend( this.defaults, options );
    // support 3d transforms
    this.support = Modernizr.csstransforms3d;
    if( this.support ) {
        this._init();
        if($(window).width() >= 991){
        this._openMenu();  // added
        }
    }
}
```